# Migrate prestashop site (in subdomain) to another domain

Tags: prestashop

I'm trying to migrate a prestashop site in subdomain to another domain.

I created the domain in the new server.

I tried to change :

**physical_uri** > /

**domain** > www.new-domain.com

**domain_ssl** > www.new-domain.com

in ps_shop_url table

and change :

**PS_SHOP_DOMAIN** > www.new-domain.com

**PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL** > www.new-domain.com

in ps_configuration

Also, i removed the subdomain from the htaccess in the main folder.

But it still showing the plesk interface.

Comment: It may be related to plesk itself or the fact that it's showing a index.html before index.php.

Comment: seems that a site shows default Plesk page on a new server where you migrated too. Make sure it resolves correctly globally to a new server IP address.

This article may be helpful to troubleshoot it further: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213372989